# How do I get the country of origin for a HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, apache, http, spring-mvc, web

I would like to form the response based on the country of origin of the HTTP client. How can I achieve it?

Comment: There are 3 backend tags in this question: `node.js`, `apache`, `spring-mvc`. In which area do you want to get country data from HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

HttpServletRequest gives all information about requests

```
public String yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request){
  System.out.println( "local contry" + request.getLocale().getCountry() );
}
```

Note that it is based on the browser configuration, I can live in US and configure my like I was in India.